# SSRS - Gauge panel error in preview

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-expression

Im trying to get a colored gauge panel to green/red based on IIF expression for comparing two dates.

This is my expression:

```
=IIF(Fields!last_Succesful_run.Value > Fields!last_Unsuccesful_run.Value, 1, 0)
```

1 = green / 0 = red

The report compiles but when viewing the preview the following error is shown:

> An error has occurred during data evaluation of the GaugePanel 'foo'.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error occurred because in the dataset there were NULL values.

This works:

```
=IIF(Fields!last_Succesful_run.Value > (IIF(IsNothing(Fields!last_Unsuccesful_run.Value ), "01.01.2000", Fields!last_Unsuccesful_run.Value)), 1, 0)
```

01.01.2000 is just an old date for showing purpose